# Can we acces a file in C or D drive or any out side drive from a html/php program file in in wamp webserver(localhost server)?

Tags: php, perl, apache, wamp

I have a simple html program. It has a link, targeted to a pdf file.
Please see the program here
**filename : invoice.html**

```
<a href="file://C:/invoice.pdf" target="_blank">My invoice</a>
```

Here when I click on the link, pdf file will be open. Working well.

**Then I called the same file from my localhost wamp server.
http://localhost/invoice.html.**

But When I call the same program from my localhost, my link is not working!!!

Can you explain me why it is not working or how I can activate the link. Is there any option in Apache server or php settings ?

Answer (score 1):

What's an "out side drive"?

> I have a simple html program

HTML is not a programming language - its a data construct / declaration.

> Here when I click on the link...Working well....http://localhost/invoice.html...not working

Does that mean that it works when you load the HTML file directly from your filesystem?

> why it is not working or how I can activate the link

Certainly it has got nothing to do with Perl, PHP, Apache nor WAMP (the tags on your post). The problem is on your browser.

> Is there any option in Apache server or php settings ?

No - because the problem is strictly client side.

I assume that the target file exists on the machine where you are running the browser.

It would have helped if you'd said which browsers you had tested this with. I would have expected it to have worked. Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

did you check if apache server is running on localhost? try to stop and restart the server and check if it works.

Comment: Yes its working well, that is why the page invoice.html loaded well , but link to outside directly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The link points to the `C:\invoice.pdf` on the client side.  I wonder if this is what you want.  It's more likely that you setup another `Directory` and `alias` in `httpd.conf` which points to `C:\`, then change the link accordingly.

Comment: I  can keep some files in outside server. Using a php/js program I wish to open all these files from local web sever  site.